# asp.net mvc how to map different view to different controller when views in the same folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question on asp.net mvc routing. How can I map two views within the same folder to different two controllers?

Controllers => TestFolder =>
     Test1Controller 
     Test2Controller

Views => TestFolder =>Test1.cshtml  Test2.cshtml

This is MapRoute I have now:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Test1",
        "Test1/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Test1", action = "Test1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Test2",
        "Test2/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Test2", action = "Test2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't map routes to views, you map routes to controllers and actions.

In your Test1Controller.Test1 method, return View("Test1"). 
In your Test2Controller.Test2 method, return View("Test2").